# Обновление Web-приложения на удаленном сервере

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat, веб-программирование

Какие есть инструменты/способы/подходы и т. д. для удаленного обновления web-приложения на tomcat? Например я добавил новый сервлет или hibernate-entity и без остановки работы текущего сайта нужно его туда закинуть. Пока что делаю вручную запаковку всего проекта в war и дальше редеплой приложения целиком, но уверен что это неправильно

Comment: Это правильно. Хотите совсем без остановки - разворачивайте приложение на двух инстансах, и обновляйте поочередно. Вот вам ссылки для размышления https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-clustering  https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-deploy-procedures

Comment: @carapuz все верно описано выше. Есть такая практика: nginx, и два(или более) app. Получается что если один из app вы обновляете - пользователи ничего не замечают, т.к. nginx использует оставшиеся app